# How can i make index in linkedlist

Tags: c

My professor said randomly make index of linked list in C. But how can I create index? I only know create node.

```
Node *get_node(int index)
{
    if (index < 0)
        return NULL;
    Node *p = head;
    for (int i = 0; i < index && p != NULL; i++) 
        p = p->next;    
    return p;
}
```

Is this create index?

Answer (score 0):

The function `get_index` returns the n-th node of the list, if any.

The `head` node should be passed as an argument instead of as a global variable:

```
Node *get_node(Node *node, int index) {
    if (index < 0)
        return NULL;
    while (node && index --> 0) 
        node = node->next;  
    return node;
}
```